# GPS Data processing with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I got some question about processing GPS Data,
I got do some research on Stackoverflow and Pandas documents...but I still can't understand how to deal with my data...

Here is my raw data's example:

**Sec,      North,        East,    Height** 
94184, 167433.988, 2529517.036,  19.623 
94185, 167434.573, 2529516.984,  19.678 
94186, 167433.788, 2529516.993,  19.598 
94187, 167433.804, 2529516.966,  19.606 
94189, 167433.852, 2529516.910,  19.604 
94190, 167433.872, 2529516.882,  19.602 
94194, 167433.919, 2529516.825,  19.602 
...

first column is time(sec),
second, third, fourth columns are coordinate locations.

You can see some data were missing, likes 94188 or 94191~94193.

I could read this txt file with pandas, but now I don't know how to deal with these questions below:

1. I want to change the 'Sec' columns to time format. I found there were lots of time format likes time-delta, datatime, etc... but I don't know which one is fit to this case ( Maybe time delta is better? 'Sec' column's numbers were a timer recording data from turn on the GPS).If time delta is good, how could I change 'Sec' column(int) to timedelta format in pandas...
2. I want to create a new continuous time dataframe to process my data, likes:

**Sec,      North,        East,    Height** 
94184, 167433.988, 2529517.036,  19.623 
94185, 167434.573, 2529516.984,  19.678 
94186, 167433.788, 2529516.993,  19.598 
94187, 167433.804, 2529516.966,  19.606 
94188,        NaN,         NaN,     NaN 
94189, 167433.852, 2529516.910,  19.604 
94190, 167433.872, 2529516.882,  19.602 
94191,        NaN,         NaN,     NaN 
94192,        NaN,         NaN,     NaN 
94193,        NaN,         NaN,     NaN 
94194, 167433.919, 2529516.825,  19.602 

I tried my code below.

```
df1 = pd.read_table('data.txt',sep='\s+', names=['T','N','E','Z'], header=None) 
df_full = pd.DataFrame({'T':np.arange(df1['T'].min(), df1['T'].max()),
                        'N':np.arange(df1['T'].min(), df1['T'].max()),
                        'E':np.arange(df1['T'].min(), df1['T'].max()),
                        'Z':np.arange(df1['T'].min(), df1['T'].max())
                    })
#Reading file successful.
```

Now I want to fill df_full's row by checking df1 and df_full have same T column value, or fill with NaN.

```
for i in range(df_full.size):
    df_full[i] = df1[df_full.T == df1.T]
```

And it's not working...

3. If I could fill my df_full with NaN successfully, now I want to interpolate the missing data, any suggest document?

Pandas is such a powerful tools, I really want to understand how to use it...

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can do it as follows:

```
In [63]: df
Out[63]:
     Sec       North         East  Height
0  94184  167433.988  2529517.036  19.623
1  94185  167434.573  2529516.984  19.678
2  94186  167433.788  2529516.993  19.598
3  94187  167433.804  2529516.966  19.606
4  94189  167433.852  2529516.910  19.604
5  94190  167433.872  2529516.882  19.602
6  94194  167433.919  2529516.825  19.602

In [64]: df = df.set_index(df.pop('Sec'))

In [65]: df
Out[65]:
            North         East  Height
Sec
94184  167433.988  2529517.036  19.623
94185  167434.573  2529516.984  19.678
94186  167433.788  2529516.993  19.598
94187  167433.804  2529516.966  19.606
94189  167433.852  2529516.910  19.604
94190  167433.872  2529516.882  19.602
94194  167433.919  2529516.825  19.602

In [66]: df = df.reindex(np.arange(df.index.min(), df.index.max()+1))

In [67]: df
Out[67]:
            North         East  Height
Sec
94184  167433.988  2529517.036  19.623
94185  167434.573  2529516.984  19.678
94186  167433.788  2529516.993  19.598
94187  167433.804  2529516.966  19.606
94188         NaN          NaN     NaN
94189  167433.852  2529516.910  19.604
94190  167433.872  2529516.882  19.602
94191         NaN          NaN     NaN
94192         NaN          NaN     NaN
94193         NaN          NaN     NaN
94194  167433.919  2529516.825  19.602

In [68]: df.interpolate()
Out[68]:
              North          East  Height
Sec
94184  167433.98800  2.529517e+06  19.623
94185  167434.57300  2.529517e+06  19.678
94186  167433.78800  2.529517e+06  19.598
94187  167433.80400  2.529517e+06  19.606
94188  167433.82800  2.529517e+06  19.605
94189  167433.85200  2.529517e+06  19.604
94190  167433.87200  2.529517e+06  19.602
94191  167433.88375  2.529517e+06  19.602
94192  167433.89550  2.529517e+06  19.602
94193  167433.90725  2.529517e+06  19.602
94194  167433.91900  2.529517e+06  19.602

In [69]: df.interpolate().reset_index()
Out[69]:
      Sec         North          East  Height
0   94184  167433.98800  2.529517e+06  19.623
1   94185  167434.57300  2.529517e+06  19.678
2   94186  167433.78800  2.529517e+06  19.598
3   94187  167433.80400  2.529517e+06  19.606
4   94188  167433.82800  2.529517e+06  19.605
5   94189  167433.85200  2.529517e+06  19.604
6   94190  167433.87200  2.529517e+06  19.602
7   94191  167433.88375  2.529517e+06  19.602
8   94192  167433.89550  2.529517e+06  19.602
9   94193  167433.90725  2.529517e+06  19.602
10  94194  167433.91900  2.529517e+06  19.602
```

Comment: @MikeChan, glad i could help :)